# How do I implement a GRing.Ring.sort

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm trying to use SSReflect's matrix library with the complex numbers from Coquelicot (http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Complex.html).

However, I get the error:

`The term "ket0" has type "matrix C (S (S O)) (S O)"
while it is expected to have type "matrix (GRing.Ring.sort ?R) ?m ?n"`

I assume that `GRing.Ring.sort` is some kind of typeclass or canonical structure, but how do I instantiate `C` as a member of that class?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Coquelicot, but based on [this page](http://coquelicot.saclay.inria.fr/html/Coquelicot.Hierarchy.html), it looks like they have their own definition of Ring (separate from mathcomp's definition). So you may need to translate between the two.

Comment: Yup, you need to connect Coq Classical real type `R` with math-comp. Fortunately this has been done many times, but it is not officially published anywhere. I suggest you ask in the math-comp mailing list for the latest copy of that file.

Comment: The latest published proof of Sophie Bernard (concerning [proofs of transcendence](https://github.com/Sobernard/Lindemann) contains two examples of such structure mappings, both for the real numbers and the complex numbers, the source code can be found directly [here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/teams/marelle/lindemann/Struct.tar.gz). I suggest the Readme.md from Sophie Bernard's site for installing instructions.